# Console application compiled as dll being used in managed winforms C++

Tags: c++, dll, reference, console, managed

I have a written a simple console application in C++ with a couple of .cpp files and one .h file. I have set the assembly to be a dll. When I create a winForms project I cannot add a reference to the dll as it's no managed code. Fair enough. So I go back to my console application and in the project's properties set Common Lanauge RunTime support to /clr.

When I try to compile I get the error:

Error   1   error D8016: '/ZI' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible

Any suggestions as to how I get my console application into managed c++ for use with a winForms project?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: A console app isn't a DLL; it's a console app. A DLL is typically functions you can call or COM/ActiveX interfaces you can use. It's not a stand-alone executable.

Comment: Just compiling a c++ app with /clr does not make it managed code.  Managed C++ is its own complex beast.  What are you actually trying to do with this program-compiled-as-DLL?

Comment: Well I was using a console to test it. I actually just created an empty project then stuck in a header file and 2 .cpp files. I thought managed C++ just built ontop of native C++? The project is just simple encryption. A couple of classes with methods exposed. I wanted to make a presentation layer ontop of it using winForms. I don't see why it can't be compiled to CLR.

Comment: C++/CLI is NOT just native C++.  It has its own additional data types, operators, and rules about memory interaction and allocation.  Just compiling with /clr does not make code magically become managed code.

Comment: My project is relatively small, so code changes should be minimal. I will only have 1 function which the managed code will use and that can be use String^. How easy is it to convert my project?

Comment: Just add the CPP and H files to your winforms project. Don't bother messing about with a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

/clr isn't compatible with /ZI

Check this page out for restrictions when using /clr: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffkc918h.aspx